# Razor Generator: ambiguous calls and resource file issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorgenerator, ambiguous-call

I'm currently trying to get Razor Generator to work with my Web Application. I have followed this tutorial http://stacktoheap.com/blog/2013/01/19/precompiling-razor-views-in-asp-dot-net-mvc-3/

I've ran into a lot of errors with my project.

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, object)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, object)'
```

and also

```
The type or namespace name 'UIStrings' does not exist in the namespace 'Resources' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

where UIStrings is just a resource file containing strings

```
</span>@Resources.UIStrings.ViewOptionsText</span>
```

I also have turned on `MVCBuildViews` and the these error don't exist until I install Razor Generator. It seems I'm lost as to why these errors are happening.